# Implicit finite element method implemented on 2D heat equation diverge at small time stem size?

Tags: numerical-methods, finite-element-method

I applied implicit FEM on the problem $$ u_t -\Delta u = f$$ using quadratic Lagrange polynomial as a basis. The system of linear equation is
$$ (M + \Delta t A)u^{n+1} = Mu^{n} + \Delta t f^n, $$ where $M_{ij} = (\phi_i,\phi_j)$ and $A_{ij} = (\nabla \phi_i,\nabla \phi_j) $. The solution and rate of convergence is correspond to theorem but the solution is blow-up in the small $\Delta t$. I think it should be unconditionally stable but the result betrayed me. I write the problem here to persuade someone who read the question to confirm the unconditionally stable condition or the result is right.

Comment: Implicit method are unconditionally stable.  So something is wrong.  (But remember: stable and accurate are two different things.)  Just to make sure, it is unstable for *small* $\Delta t$?  Never heard of that before.  What happens if you set $f=0$?

Comment: @bob.sacamento What is the initial condition for $f = 0$? I will set it now.

Comment: I mean, just set $f=0$ for all $n$, including initially.  Of course, if you want to see anything interesting happen, you'll have to set $u$ to something other than a constant.  Anything that doesn't violate your spatial boundary conditions should be fine.  You're just testing, after all.  (Now that I think about it, you might *want* to set $u$ to a constant.  If anything "happens" then, you will know for sure that something is wrong.)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! At least you confirm that the code is wrong. It still blow-up but at least I know what I have to do next. :)

Comment: Well, that's progress!  :-)

Comment: The correct form should be $(M + \Delta t K) u^{n+1} = M u^n + \Delta t F$ with $M_{ij} = (\phi_i, \phi_j), K_{ij} = (\nabla \phi_i, \nabla \phi_j), F_i = (\phi_i, f)$. Absence of $M$ before $u^n$ might blow the scheme. Usually $I$ stands for identity matrix/operator, so I discourage you from using $I$ for something else

Comment: @uranix Ok I see. In fact, I use that form but it still blow-up. Thank you for your comment. I will edit my question.

Answer (score 2):

This scheme is unconditionally stable in the energy norm $\|u\|_A^2 = (Au, u)$
$$
M \frac{u^{n+1} - u^n}{\Delta t} + A u^{n+1} = f^n\\
\left(M + \frac{\Delta t}{2} A\right) \frac{u^{n+1} - u^n}{\Delta t} 
- A \frac{u^{n+1} - u^n}{2} 
+ A u^{n+1} = f^n\\
\left(M + \frac{\Delta t}{2} A\right) \frac{u^{n+1} - u^n}{\Delta t} 
+ A \frac{u^{n+1} + u^n}{2} = f^n\\
$$
Now multiply both sides with $u^{n+1} - u^n$ to get
$$
\frac{1}{\Delta t} \|u^{n+1} - u^n\|_{M + \frac{\Delta t}{2}A}^2
+ \frac{1}{2} \left(\|u^{n+1}\|^2_A - \|u^n\|^2_A\right) = (f^n, u^{n+1} - u^n).
$$
$$
\|u^{n+1}\|^2_A = \|u^n\|^2_A 
- \frac{1}{\Delta t} \|u^{n+1} - u^n\|_{M + \frac{\Delta t}{2}A}^2
+ \underbrace{2 (f^n, u^{n+1} - u^n)}_{O(\Delta t)}.
$$
This shows that for $f = 0$ the $\|u^n\|_A^2$ not increases in time. And if $f$ is not zero then $\|u^n\|_A^2$ increases as much as $n \cdot O(\Delta t)$ which is limited.

The proof for $f \neq 0$ is sloppy (the $n \cdot O(\Delta t)$ part), but for the case when $f = 0$ the proof is solid and could be checked in practice directly by evaluating $\|u^n\|_A^2 = (Au^n, u^n)$ on each time step. The sequence of $\|u^n\|_A^2$ must be non increasing.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with this, but I haven't seen a mention of $u_0$ (the initial data) in the entire response. Shouldn't error approximations depend on $u_0$?

Comment: @UserA This proof connects $u^{n+1}$ norm with $u^n$ norm. If you write a chain of inequalities it will eventually end with $u^0$ which is precisely the initial condition
$$
\|u^{n+1}\|_A^2 \leq \|u^{n}\|_A^2 \leq \|u^{n-1}\|_A^2 \leq \dots \leq \|u^0\|_A^2
$$